# Does the Assign method of TStringList copy the list of strings from source to destination, or does it simply copy the pointers?

Tags: delphi, assign, tstringlist

I'm having trouble with the vague terminology of the documentation of the `TStringList.Assign` method. The word "set" in

> If Source is of type TStringList, the list is **set** to the list of the source `TStringList` object, and if associated objects are supported, any associated objects are **copied** from Source as well.

can be interpreted in multiple ways. Is the `TStringList` object **copied** from the source to the destination, leaving the source intact... or is the destination set to **point** to the source object without copying anything? The implication of the latter is that if I then free the destination object, the source object is also freed. Or?

This statement in the documentation for `TStrings.AddObject`, which is how the Strings are added to the destination, further muddies the waters for me:

> Note: The `TStrings` object does not own the objects you add this way. Objects added to the `TStrings` object still exist even if the `TStrings` instance is destroyed. They must be explicitly destroyed by the application.

Does this mean that I have to do more than calling `.Free` to destroy the destination `TStringList` when I am done with it?

Comment: It's a copy. You can change or free either one without affecting the other.

Comment: And yes, any associated objects are your responsibility. In Delphi, an object variable (like `x: TButton`) is merely a reference to the heap object.

Comment: Then I have a different problem then. I have an access violation that only occurs if I run a Mac app by itself, rather than from the IDE, so I cannot debug it!

Comment: We cannot help you with a problem we can't see. Show us your code.

Comment: @nolaspeaker If the error does not show up with the debugger then I have no idea where in the code this is happening. I took out the Assign statements since I realized I don't need an intermediate step to extract the values. I can just get them from the TObjectDictionary directly. Runtime error is still there, but still doesn't happen when the debugger is running, only when I run the app standalone.

Comment: @JuanJimenez Isolate the problem into the tiniest project possible, then everone else is able to see it crashing without debugger. This helps you also excluding what could be the cause (i.e. wrong expectations).

Comment: I have made the Github repo for the app public. https://github.com/IIUSA/intents-editor-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TStringList.Assign()` *copies* the strings and object pointers from the source `TStringList`. Just know that this is a shallow copy not a deep copy, since `string` is a reference-counted type.

Comment: Copy on write for strings means that it behaves as if it were a deep copy

Answer (score 1):

You can think of Assign being implemented as follows:

```
PROCEDURE TStrings.Assign(Source : TStrings);
  VAR
    I : INTEGER;

  BEGIN
    Clear;
    FOR I:=0 TO PRED(Source.Count) DO AddObject(Source.Items[I],Source.Items.Objects[I])
  END;
```

The actual behind-the-scenes implementation may vary, but seen from outside, this is the logical operation of the Assign method.

(the attached Objects for each String are copied as references, so they point to the same instance as in the source)